# How to get the name of the method (@action)?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

```
class UserStore {
  @observable rules = {
      data:[],
      isFeatching: false,
      error:false,
  };
    @observable rooms = {
      data:[],
      isFeatching: false,
      error:false,
  };
    @observable money = {
      data:[],
      isFeatching: false,
      error:false,
  };

  @action
  async getRules() {
    try {
       this.rules.isFeatching = true;
       const data = await api.getRules();
       this.rules.isFeatching = false;
    }
  }

  @action
  async getRooms() {
    try {
       this.rooms.isFeatching = true;
       const data = await api.getRooms();
       this.rooms.isFeatching = false;
    }
  }

  @action
  async getMoney() {
    try {
       this.money.isFeatching = true;
       const data = await api.getMoney();
       this.money.isFeatching = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Help me please.

Conditions of the problem:
1) I need to get three types of data in one Store.

Task Objective:
1) How to make it so that "isFeatching" is automatically placed?
 
Is there any way to automate?

I had the following thought:
Create a global array (or a class from which I will inherit):

```
const globalManagerFetching = {UserStore: {
    getRules: {isFeatching:false}
    getRooms: {isFeatching:false}
    getMoney: {isFeatching:false}
}
```

But how to do it?
  How can I get the name action?

my pseudocode:

```
  @action
 async getMoney() {
     const methoneName = 'getMoney'; // how to get it automatically?
   try {
      globalManagerFetching[this.constructor.name][methoneName] = false;
      const data = await api.getMoney();
      globalManagerFetching[this.constructor.name][methoneName] = true;
   }
 }
```

my pseudocode other:

```
  @action
 async getMoney() {
   try {
      setFetching(true);//how to do this?
      const data = await api.getMoney();
      setFetching(false);//how to do this?

   }
 }
```

Tell me please.
Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the context of your question correct - you would like to avoid code duplication. I would recommend to solve you this by restructuring your code in such a way:

```
const { getRules, getRooms, getMoney} = api;

class UserStoreResource {
  @observable data = [];
  @observable isFetching = false;
  @observable error;

  constructor(fetchFunction) {
    this.fetchData  = async ( ) => {
      this.isFetching = ture;
      await fetchFunction();
      this.isFetching = false;
    }  
  }
}

class UserStore {
  rules = new UserStoreResource(getRules);
  rooms = new UserStoreResource(getRooms);
  money = new UserStoreResource(getMoney);

  @action
  async fetchAllData() {
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        this.rules.fetchData(),
        this.rooms.fetchData(),
        this.money.fetchData(),
        ])
    }
  }
}
```

If in your components you will use any observable from UserStoreResource - you will get correct rerendering.

Answering your question about getting a function name - its possible by requesting a property `arguments.callee.name` - but this is deprecated functionality. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee). Most of all - if you need this property - this is an indicator that code requires restructure.

Answer (score 0):

you can get function name like this

```
const methodName = arguments.callee.name
```